# Cannot create site from template because of Attachments folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

I have created a site template with a list and some content inside the list. When I try to create a site from that template, I get and error message saying "**something went wrong**", when I tried to create `site/lists/list name/Attachments/1`. None of items in the list have attachments. Has anyone come across this issue and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was coming from having a lookup column in the list that was looking up another column in the same list. SharePoint does not like that in it's templates.